Is it correct to say that a D Flip Flop only stores a given value for a single Clock Cycle?
With respect to D Flip-Flop's, is it correct to say that a given value is only stored for the duration of one Clock Cycle?
I'm completely new to the topic of Flip Flops, but I believe I have a solid understanding of both the SR and JK Flip Flops. With both of these Flip Flop circuits, a value persists across multiple clock cycles even after the input option utilised to input that value is deactivated (and is only changed after invoking the appropriate Set (S/J) or Reset (R/K) option (on the next clock edge).
Both SR and JK Flip Flops have two inputs, while D Flip Flops only have one input (D). My understanding is that the value of D is captured on each execution of the clock cycle, hence my question about the value only being persisted for a single clock cycle, i.e. in order for 1 to be persisted across multiple clock cycles, the input into the associated D Flip Flop would need to remain as 1 throughout (or at least be equal to 1 at the clock edge).

If we assume an edge sensitive D-flip-flop (common case), then basically, yes.
You can think of a DFF as sampling the D input on each sensitive edge of the clock. So for a rising edge triggered DFF, every rising edge of the clock will cause the value of the output Q to be updated to match the current input D.
Between clock edges It doesn't matter what the value of D is (ignoring metastability concerns), the output Q will not change during this time.
If the value of D remains constant across multiple clock cycles, the output Q will  remain constant, because each clock cycle it samples the same value.

Some DFFs have an additional clock enable input. This can be used to allow the DFF to ignore a clock edge. So for example if you wanted to ignore one or more clock edges (e.g. update on every second clock), you could use the enable signal for this purpose.

You're on the right track but you're not entirely correct. The value is stored in a D Flip-Flop from one clock edge to the next and will persist across multiple clock cycles until a new clock edge occurs that captures a new value from the D input. The value will remain unchanged during the time between these clock edges, regardless of what happens to the D input in between. In comparison to the SR and JK Flip-Flops, they have more complex behavior due to their additional inputs. They can set, reset, or toggle based on the specific inputs provided, but like the D Flip-Flop, once a value is stored on a clock edge, it persists until the next relevant clock event. The D Flip-Flop is simpler in that it directly stores whatever is on the D input at the clock edge.


With respect to D Flip-Flop's, is it correct to say that a given value is only stored for the duration of one Clock Cycle?

Sort of, though that's a clumsy, and so possible to misinterpret, way to say it.
A better way of saying it would be that the value is stored until the next active clock edge, at which point the data is replaced by the value of the data input that meets the setup and hold times with respect to the active clock edge.
Note that some D flops, the venerable 7474 for instance, have additional set and reset inputs.
You may think the setup and hold requirements are being overly picky. Maybe, but if they are ignored, it stops being a digital system, and starts being a much more complicated analog system, with an uncertain output, and possible metastable (actually breaks digital systems!) behaviour.
